# request location update on boot

Tags: android, android-location

I'm new to android. I need a get current device location /not last known location/. So I'm starting service on boot. This service request location update using `LocationManager`. I have a following questions.

1. Is it right way to request location update in background service on boot?
2. Is there any best practice?
3. I have an another server. This service need found location /I need latitude and longitude/. How to get that location in second service?

Thank you for every advice.

Sorry for poor English.

Zeck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of writing a library that handles this and similar things. I just started so there's not much but fortunately the basic location getter is available.

Have a look at : https://github.com/sfarooq/A-droid-lib

All you need to do is implement the `AsyncCaller` interface and then call :

```
new AsyncGetLocation(this).execute();
```

from somewhere in your class and a location will be returned to the `onBackgroundTaskCompleted()` method. 
If you want to do a loading dialog while this happens, you can implement the `AsyncStarting` interface which has the `onBackgroundTaskStarting()` method definition where you can add a dialog.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for reply. I want to become contributor. :)

Comment: Yeah... I could use some help. Just fork it and contact me via GitHub

Comment: Thank you. I'm folk your project.